# Running Xvfb from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, xvfb

I am working on a server with no X servers and trying to run a script that uses spynner module, which requires an X server. For this purpose, I want to run Xvfb.

I can run the script by calling it via `xvfb-run`, i.e.:

```
xvfb-run python2.6 try.py.
```

This works with no problem. However, I need to invoke Xvfb from within the script. For this purpose, I tried using subprocess as follows:

```
xvfb = subprocess.Popen(['Xvfb', ':99'])
```

After adding this piece of code to the beginning of the script, and trying to run the script as

```
python2.6 try.py
```

I get the message:

```
: cannot connect to X server
```

Is there something else I need to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to add:

```
import os
os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":99"
```

so that when it goes to open the connection to the X server it'll be able to find the Xvfb instance you've started

Answer (score 5):

For future visitors, it is worth mentioning that [PyVirtualDisplay](http://ponty.github.com/PyVirtualDisplay/) offers an abstraction over Xvfb to make it easy to use from Python.